# Precompiling server-side html templates using grunt

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, gruntjs

Using Grunt I was wondering if there were some existing build process to precompile server-side templates.
Actually with usual template engines, you often use features like "include", "extend layout.html", ...
This means you could be able to just precompile your template doing all stuff that can be 
"statically" solve. For example with [ect](http://ectjs.com/) and the "include" feature:

- a.ect

`<div>Hello I'm <%= @name %></div><% include 'b.ect' %>`

- b.ect

`<div>I'm included in a.ect</div>`

Since there is no conditional dynamic statement to decide if the *b.ect* block has to be included, *a.ect* could be statically compiled including *b.ect* into *./dist/a.ect*:

`<div>Hello I'm <%= @name %></div><div>I'm included in a.ect</div>`

As you can see, *./dist/a.ect* is still a template, and the @name variable stills need to be  provided, so in this case, this part remains unchanged. However, the inclusion is static so it can be done right now avoiding the useless inclusion **at runtime** (even with a cache)

Using this approach, we could even think about minifying templates during this build process, and more. For the minifying task, I am aware of tools like htmlmin but this is oriented for valid html.

I've also found some grunt tasks ([grunt-ect](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ect), [grunt-contrib-jade](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jade), etc) which compiles your templates into html by providing the context. However it seems that it expects to get all the dynamic parts of your templates i.e. the value of all variables.

Any idea if this kind of *precompilation* tool already exists for a template engine even without grunt?

PS: This could be a bad approach, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not excactly what you are looking for, 
but there's a precompiler for [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templates available via npm, which renders templates in one minified js file:

https://npmjs.org/package/handlebars-precompiler

Comment: Yes I've already looked at it, but it looks more like a client-side tool. Anyway I'm not sure this precompiler is well compatible with Express, it generates JS.

Comment: maybe this one ? https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake/ Not sure that this package does including on fly but maybe someone find it interesting.